# Can't run Code Playground example from local file

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, google-playground

This is the Map/Earth Integration example at Google's 'Code Playground' site:
  https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#maps/earth_integration

I can run that example from the playground just fine.  But if I save its html locally and then try to load that file in Chrome, the browser just stalls indefinitely with:
  Installed Plugin Version: Loading...

An Android app of mine that attempts to load the same example into a WebView does the same thing. That app works fine when running html that employs the API V3 javascript.

The Chrome browser's Developer Tools debugger stops on line 15:
 "google.load("maps", "2.x");"

saying that "google" is not defined.  It also reports that 'GMap2' (line 18) and 
  "GET file://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQetc" (line 10) are also not defined.

The Map/Earth Integration example html includes a (long) jsapi key.  Do I need to get my own jsapi key maybe?  Where do I get one?  I have a v2.API_KEY from:
  "https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~elite-rider-459/apiui/credential"

but I'm not sure if it will work with Google Earth and Google Earth is not among the available choices at the "APIs % auth" page at that console website:

I remember reading that Google Earth no longer requires such a key.  Can anyone tell me
what I'm missing?  And how to stop Google Earth from embedding itself in my desktop?  I tried removing and reinstalling the plug-in, but GE continues to do so.

Thanks,
  Ted

Answer (score 0):

When you run this example from local filesystem you must prepend the `http:` -protocol to the `<script/>`-src , otherwise the browser will try to load the API from your filesystem(what of course will fail)

Answer (score 0):

When I ran "Marker V3" code example in Google's Code Playground under "Maps V3" section, on local file, the code didn't execute. I had to add "http:" to script tag that loads Google maps in order to run the code locally.